# latex error in compiling the IEEE pattern

Tags: overleaf, ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf, ieeeaccess

i am having an error in the IEEE pattern where their is gap created in the tex and that remains empty in one page while the text is half on that page and the remaining is shifted to the other page..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtDpZ.png)[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It's well nigh impossible to diagnose the situation on the basis of the screenshot you posted. Please edit your query to post some sample code that gives rise to the issue you wish to fix.